# docker ignores daemon.json file

Tags: docker

I'm trying to add a mirror to my docker in order to use my server
to cache images from docker hub using the following syntax:
/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
 "registry-mirrors": ["https://myserver.com"]
}
```

I have seen the above config even docker's official documentation.
but my ubuntu 20.04 does not read that file at all. Even if I restart the
docker service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite the configuration file as follow:

```
{
 "registry-mirrors": ["myserver.com"]
}
```

**Remove the protocol!**

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

Added a directive to `daemon.json` which was just being ignored when I restarted Docker. Docker was restarting without error, it was just ignoring my change.

### Problem

I was attempting to change the default log target to `syslog` from `json-file` by **APPENDING** the `log-driver` directive to the end of `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (I was scripting my Docker install and so was building this file incrementally).

But no matter WHAT I did, I could not get the change read. The output of `docker info --format '{{.LoggingDriver}}'` was always `json-file`.

### Troubleshooting

Investigated the potential of a formatting error like the accepted answer, but this bore no fruit. Reading, re-reading of the Docker docs. Googling.  Nothing could clear the error.

### Solution

The Problem? Looks like Docker was really finicky about the **ORDER** the logging directive `"log-driver"` appeared.  After wasting hours and beating my brains in, I changed the order the directive appeared in the file by **PREPENDING** it to the top of `daemon.json` like so:

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "default-address-pools":
  [
    {"base":"192.168.X.X/24","size":28}
  ]
}
```

With the directive at the TOP, the change was recognized after restarting Docker and the output of `docker info --format '{{.LoggingDriver}}'` was now as expected: `syslog`. Go figure...

### Conclusion

It was a silly problem, but wow did it waste some cycles figuring out how things were broken.  Hope this get folks like myself out of a hole who couldn't find this solution Googling-